# Сложность алгоритма сортировки

Tags: массивы, сортировка

Провожу исследовательскую работу на тему сортировок массивов. В процессе возник один вопрос. Можно ли узнать, сколько перестановок совершит программа для наихудшего случая, зная сложность алгоритма?

Comment: Знаю, что есть один алгоритм, который рандомно переставляет элементы, затем проверяет - отсортирован ли массив(вроде болотный называется).
Так вот в нем наихудший случай - бесконечность.

Comment: @Silento это Bogosort или Shotgun Sort

Comment: Смотрите в Википедии [Список алгоритмов сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8), там указана сложность.

Answer (score 2):

Есть разные меры сложности. Для ответа важны две: *сложность в среднем*, и *сложность в наихудшем случае*.

Последний вариант неинтересен: если известна сложность алгоритма в наихудшем случае, то есть число операций в наихудшем случае, то вопрос вырождается в тавтологию.

Первый вариант интереснее - если известна сложность алгоритма в среднем, можем ли мы сказать что-нибудь о сложности в наихудшем случае. Если и можем, то немногое. Алгоритмы сортировки слиянием и быстрой сортировки имеют одинаковую асимптотику сложности в среднем, O(n log n), однако, в наихудшем случае сортировка слиянием также имеет асимптотику O(n log n), в то время как быстрая сортировка в наихудшем случае имеет сложность O(n^2). Этот пример показывает, что сложность в среднем не позволяет делать однозначных выводов о сложности в наихудшем случае.